# Solve non linear equations using Newton iterative method in matlab

Tags: matlab, jacobian

I have 3 non linear equations where the variables are $a,b,\phi$. Equations are 
$$ \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} = -1 + \frac{1}{1.2}\times \cos(\phi)$$
$$ \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} = \frac{1}{1.2}\times \sin(\phi)$$
$$ \arg((\frac{x- jy}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}})-a) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \phi$$

Where  $x = \cos(a) - ab\sin(a) - 1$ and $y = ab\cos(a) + \sin(a)$
$x$ & $y$ are functions of $a$.

I tried to solve it but the problem is whatever initial value I choose, I couldn't get inverse of Jacobian Matrix.

Reference: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3sv4hs5z5jn3mfr/xyz.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have terms in the denominator because of numerical reasons. If possible rearrange the square root terms (bring them maybe to the other side). That should work then.

Furthermore, there are ways to solve it without the Jacobian. Find the right algorithm that does not require it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, conding exactly as you wrote your equations and using the built-in function [fsolve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) to solve the nonlinear system of equations:

```
x0 = ones(3,1);
x = fsolve(@fun,x0)

function F = fun(v)
    a = v(1);
    b = v(2);
    phi = v(3);

    x = cos(a)-a*b*sin(a)-1;
    y = a*b*cos(a)+sin(a);

    F = zeros(size(v));
    F(1) = x/sqrt(x^2+y^2)+1-1/1.2*cos(phi);
    F(2) = y/sqrt(x^2+y^2)-1/1.2*sin(phi);
    F(3) = angle((x-1j*y)/sqrt(x^2+y^2)-a)-pi/2+phi;
end

x =

    0.0000
    0.9373
    2.1415
```

Notice the initial estimate is the array `x0=[1 1 1]'`, but you may change the initial estimate depending on the answer you are looking for. As a matter of fact, I get different responses if I change my initial estimate:

```
x0 = rand(3,1);
x = fsolve(@fun,x0)

x =

    0.0000
    0.4286
    1.5623

x =

    0.0000
    0.8596
    1.7091

x =

   -5.4063
 -924.2031
    1.5346
```

(run the code 3 times and get 3 different responses)